# new relic synthetics strange http response codes -7,-20, -9999

Tags: http

Looking at the synthetics page of the new relic monitoring tool we have in place, I'm seeing unfamiliar http status codes in the http response codes panel, for example -7, -20 and -9999

Is this usual? Anyone know what these would mean/where they would be coming from?

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tool (maybe adding links would help) but those error codes are not only "unfamiliar" they are "illegal" under the standard!

Answer (score 1):

The -7 response code indicates that a timeout has occurred requesting the resource.

From the [Synthetics documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/synthetics/new-relic-synthetics/using-monitors/synthetics-response-codes):

> New Relic Synthetics returns a number of additional response codes beyond standard HTTP response codes, visible in the Resources page. These response codes are based on Chromium's response codes  and give you more detail on the behavior of your monitors

A full summary of the extra response codes supported is available at that URL.